# Flutter application not working correctly with burp proxy

Tags: android, flutter, testing, burp

I have a Flutter application. I have to perform a penetration test on it. I used proxydroid to intercept requests since normal proxy settings don't work with this app. I successfully see the requests on burp, and receive a response from the server. However as soon as the response is sent to the application, a generic error message appears. I already thought about a parsing error. Without burp or with tls passthrough the app works perfectly. How can I understand what may cause the problem? I also tried to change iptables settings and set up invisible proxy on burp settings. The behaviour of the app is still the same. Is there something about flutter that understands that I use a proxy and stops the application from working properly? technically the application is set up by the developers to facilitate penetration tests so I don't expect any additional controls.

Comment: Could be a technical problem of Burp so I would check other proxies like Mitmproxy or Charles. Even if you say the app is set-up for a pen test, it could still contain something like certificate pinning, even if checking the cert after receiving the response would be extremely unusual. So a technical reason like an incompatibility e.g. HTTP 2.0 or a changed encoding of the response would be my guess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Robert. I tried with mitmproxy but it still gives me the same error. Also removing http 2.0 didn't make any difference. I removed all configurations that could indicate a modification of the response, but still nothing.